# How to pass the value to display the result without crash in kotlin when passing the null safety

Tags: kotlin

I just started to begin kotlin in android studio by adding the two numbers. 
Let's say if second number passed as null, how to achieve that to consider as 0.

Here is code.

```
fun addition(n:Int?,n1:Int?):Int{
        return (n?: 0)+ n1!!
    }
```

Case 1: (Success)

addition(null,5)

This is displaying as 5.//Correct

Case 2: (Crash) -> Failure

addition(5,null)

In the case 2 scenario, it's crashing. I tried adding return (n?: 0)+ **n1?** But it shows compile error as type mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save them in two values :

```
fun sum(n: Int?, n1: Int?): Int {
        val a1 = n ?: 0
        val a2 = n1 ?: 0

        return a1 + a2
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
fun addition(n:Int?,n1:Int?):Int = (n ?: 0) + (n1 ?: 0)
```